# Multi polygon data into map individual shapes using R or Ironpython [Not using QGIS or any tools]

Tags: r, ironpython, geojson, shapefile, spotfire

i had an API which gives output as JSON[geoJson] in that i had multipolygon data. I need to convert that multi polygon data into a shape which can we store in the form of table and then use it on Spotfire Map chart .

sample data :`

```
{
    "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  [-75.32514184,39.68400504],
                  [-75.28309437,39.67102372],
                  [-75.25492525,39.67324011],
                  [-75.23387462,39.65835152],
                  [-75.19796059,39.65996532],
                  [-75.06312747,39.56445401],
                  [-75.07120777,39.55508892],
                  [-75.06670734,39.51146806],
                  [-75.08235677,39.45373235],
                  [-75.23602786,39.5518305],
                  [-75.32689178,39.48724325],
                  [-75.35152833,39.48086866],
                  [-75.37849208,39.45593926],
                  [-75.40463162,39.45864363],
                  [-75.41793034,39.4520669],
                  [-75.4208984,39.43171165],
                  [-75.41287955,39.42069868],
                  [-75.42334002,39.40908281],
                  [-75.41567225,39.37497182],
                  [-75.55276304,39.49051431],
                  [-75.51668888,39.56656844],
                  [-75.57023421,39.61773498],
                  [-75.48928066,39.71485823],
                  [-75.47597428,39.72008438],
                  [-75.47476843,39.74183207],
                  [-75.46039411,39.76336204],
                  [-75.42764732,39.77824291],
                  [-75.40803867,39.77338307],
                  [-75.36488492,39.71461408],
                  [-75.32514184,39.68400504]
                ]
              ],
              [
                [
                  [-75.19757186,40.57068432],
                  [-75.182282,40.55679913],
                  [-75.12452604,40.56479881],
                  [-75.07978594,40.54535598],
                  [-75.06367965,40.52100347],
                  [-75.07011864,40.45625391],
                  [-75.05745333,40.42017147],
                  [-75.02126613,40.4013236],
                  [-75.00047551,40.40862108],
                  [-74.97284101,40.40444796],
                  [-74.95018845,40.34547383],
                  [-74.93250297,40.3337744],
                  [-74.92115001,40.31403375],
                  [-74.88065956,40.29959161],
                  [-74.84276309,40.24845279],
                  [-74.73882471,40.17772566],
                  [-74.72548045,40.14930669],
                  [-74.74629412,40.1243587],
                  [-74.82902248,40.11616097],
                  [-74.87192415,40.07805656],
                  [-74.9562015,40.05801445],
                  [-74.98348534,40.03407384],
                  [-74.9909242,40.04465186],
                  [-74.96679134,40.08136388],
                  [-74.96575349,40.11082049],
                  [-75.02146501,40.13460854],
                  [-75.49415542,40.42013163],
                  [-75.42272874,40.4879267],
                  [-75.34505956,40.53743815],
                  [-75.20038756,40.61474324],
                  [-75.19351301,40.58376852],
                  [-75.19757186,40.57068432]
                ]
              ],
              [
                [
                  [-75.89413094,40.6821145],
                  [-75.53214441,40.444312],
                  [-75.69520415,40.25578995],
                  [-75.7021404,40.24364402],
                  [-75.88703342,40.14047856],
                  [-75.94004823,40.10940121],
                  [-75.94705762,40.03603265],
                  [-75.99369893,39.96041958],
                  [-75.9906617,39.93362969],
                  [-76.00770601,39.92159432],
                  [-75.99553569,39.87247767],
                  [-76.01428155,39.86453921],
                  [-76.01753914,39.8518823],
                  [-76.03133352,39.85113818],
                  [-76.02860946,39.83795877],
                  [-76.0426554,39.82451971],
                  [-76.04603499,39.80551525],
                  [-76.07679711,39.76370281],
                  [-76.08939373,39.76248572],
                  [-76.09452067,39.74485836],
                  [-76.11239705,39.74868787],
                  [-76.1079719,39.73004603],
                  [-76.11399935,39.72739475],
                  [-76.12874755,39.73843777],
                  [-76.14267942,39.72906497],
                  [-76.13922315,39.72222927],
                  [-76.23312186,39.72185359],
                  [-76.22108224,39.69271387],
                  [-76.16150967,39.6490226],
                  [-76.15306364,39.62173306],
                  [-76.12477283,39.60192838],
                  [-76.07817857,39.54247537],
                  [-76.15419975,39.40204622],
                  [-76.22633838,39.3749984],
                  [-76.36371047,39.39338795],
                  [-76.39872145,39.23125239],
                  [-76.53098126,39.24272631],
                  [-76.60371537,39.25946088],
                  [-76.56481893,39.23155306],
                  [-76.57666765,39.1982283],
                  [-76.6106352,39.22463686],
                  [-76.65990783,39.22724204],
                  [-76.70169546,39.20802745],
                  [-76.7140328,39.2203449],
                  [-76.7347856,39.22319433],
                  [-76.74475777,39.23503875],
                  [-76.78911638,39.25433684],
                  [-76.77872532,39.28419436],
                  [-76.79216888,39.30738749],
                  [-76.83671036,39.31261711],
                  [-76.87876483,39.33187319],
                  [-76.90065426,39.34648696],
                  [-76.92270361,39.34160401],
                  [-76.98031473,39.3540965],
                  [-77.02381821,39.34338861],
                  [-77.04635592,39.35344398],
                  [-77.07254804,39.35172357],
                  [-77.08854725,39.36311025],
                  [-77.17430298,39.34750071],
                  [-77.46170713,39.21873535],
                  [-77.46466727,39.2291606],
                  [-77.49377347,39.25001468],
                  [-77.54190077,39.26904209],
                  [-77.56867294,39.29849507],
                  [-77.61623578,39.29981856],
                  [-77.67930192,39.31878102],
                  [-77.62302605,39.44939558],
                  [-77.61837213,39.51512972],
                  [-77.59396538,39.54824064],
                  [-77.57493792,39.60854189],
                  [-77.54868487,39.63167368],
                  [-77.52181365,39.63712104],
                  [-77.4913493,39.66794682],
                  [-77.49253971,39.68245366],
                  [-77.50390018,39.68744306],
                  [-77.47579338,39.71962322],
                  [-77.46443301,39.7200735],
                  [-77.2210509,39.72067934],
                  [-76.99681224,39.72089164],
                  [-76.99427809,39.82560351],
                  [-76.96703948,39.86538637],
                  [-76.99082852,39.8904215],
                  [-76.9719749,39.92706488],
                  [-76.97904739,39.9443222],
                  [-77.01294532,39.98798394],
                  [
                    -77.02412991,
                    40.02021724
                  ],
                  [
                    -77.06432239,
                    40.02670917
                  ],
                  [
                    -77.09718273,
                    40.05674111
                  ],
                  [
                    -77.1427693,
                    40.07183872
                  ],
                  [
                    -77.02626522,
                    40.15171024
                  ],
                  [
                    -77.00397151,
                    40.15661603
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.97813766,
                    40.15197387
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.97020274,
                    40.16735817
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.91605529,
                    40.16621408
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.91354518,
                    40.17889763
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.925516,
                    40.18756812
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.90984481,
                    40.1893077
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.91812295,
                    40.20793809
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.90177271,
                    40.21919889
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.86023727,
                    40.21763508
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.84629048,
                    40.2284457
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.75587155,
                    40.17806695
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.73823145,
                    40.1394215
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.71352729,
                    40.14289677
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.70318197,
                    40.15416892
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.68152954,
                    40.15357783
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.66934549,
                    40.16664675
                  ],
                  [
                    -76.65494102,
                    40.16337392
                  ],
                  [-76.63846169,40.18321378],
                  [-76.6222033,40.18355724],
                  [-76.61003448,40.19435647],
                  [-76.57692258,40.19457037],
                  [-76.68030003,40.47145042],
                  [-76.54076901,40.5566447],
                  [-76.43820405,40.49596254],
                  [-76.32657241,40.52038146],
                  [-76.3000132,40.51740636],
                  [-76.17685231,40.53886089],
                  [-76.13768022,40.56248514],
                  [-76.01199062,40.57274302],
                  [-76.06453981,40.58844415],
                  [-76.01865397,40.58247062],
                  [-75.90011289,40.63802331],
                  [-75.89413094,40.11461145]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
}
```

any ideas please

Comment: That isn't valid JSON

Comment: sorry i missed bracket  ,edited

Answer (score 0):

Assume shp is your example stored as a character variable:

```
 library(sf)
 x <- read_sf(shp)
 plot(x)
```

This doesn't convert it to a table, but it does read the geojson text in, convert it to a simple feature, and then allows you to plot it with the objects own method.

Comment: it is coming as list element and this function is not working with that format

Comment: I'm not quite following. Do you mean a list element in R?

Comment: If its just a list item then you can get to it with something like `shp[[1]]`. Or is the geometry in a nested r list?